# How to resolve "undefined" result being returned after an image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following captures 3 properties from a query, one of which is `friendRequestId`

```
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        var friends = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            friends.push({
                imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username')
            });
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < friends.length; j++) {

            $('#container').append('<img class="images" src="' + friends[j].imageURL + '" data-friend-request-id="' + friends[j].friendRequestId + '" />');
            }
```

---

From the query the user sees an image displayed on the page via

```
<div class = "FriendSelected" id="container"></div>
```

---

When the user clicks the image, the following code should capture the `friendRequestId` value and save it to the variable `friendRequestId`

At the moment, "undefined" is returning as the result. I'm unsure if this is because of a problem with my code or that the as per screen shot the image is actually held within a div container? Not sure how to fix this?

Im sure I should use `friendRequestId` even though console log is returning this as `data-friend-request-id` ?

Here is the code thats not working

```
$(document).on("click",".FriendSelected",function(e){
    alert(e.source).data("friendRequestId");
    var friendRequestId = $(e.source).data("friendRequestId");
});
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the click call?

Comment: You seem to have posted the part of the code that works instead of the part of the code that doesn't.

Comment: class = "FriendSelected"

Comment: Always post the code.  Never post pictures of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write event on images class which is added on img tag not the div tag class and you have to do [`event delegation`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as images are appended dynamically after DOM load and you need to use `data()` to get `friend-request-id` value or you can use `attr()` method like this:

```
$("div.FriendSelected").on("click",".images",function(){


var friendId = $(this).data("friend-request-id");

// or alternate can be to use attr()

var friendId = $(this).attr("data-friend-request-id");

});
```

Comment: You don't "have to" use event delegation, but it is an option. And you don't "need to" use `data()`, and often probably shouldn't.

Comment: it is needed as images are being appended on page after DOM load

Comment: It isn't needed. There's no reason a person can't bind event handlers to new elements directly. It's just an alternate solution.

Comment: may be you are right but i used to do like this on dynamic html

Comment: And it's a good approach in many cases. However, his question states that `undefined` is being logged, so he must be binding successfully one way or another. The part of your answer describing how to fetch the data attribute is more likely the solution he needs.

Comment: yes i agree with you but as OP has not posted event so i wrote one

Answer (score 1):

Given that I've been following your other questions, here's a JSFiddle that shows the concept in a way that relates to your other code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kd4pS/3/

Basically if you wrap your image and name output in some kind of wrapper, you can then attach a 'click' handler to your container that will catch the event at the wrapper layer as follows:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.wrapper', function() {
    console.log(this);
    var wrapper = $(this);
    // either of these work
    console.log(wrapper.data('friendRequestId'));
    console.log(wrapper.data('friend-request-id'));
    // remove selected from all wrappers in case one was already selected
    $('#container .wrapper').removeClass('selected');
    // mark clicked wrapper as selected
    wrapper.addClass('selected');
    // save friendRequestId
    window.selectedFriendRequestId = wrapper.data('friendRequestId');
    // enabled button
    $('#simulateAddBadge').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

In this case I've used the simplest approach of saving the `selectedFriendRequestId` as a property on `window`.

You can then access this saved value from your other code as follows:

```
$('#simulateAddBadge').on('click', function() {
    alert('add badge for friend request: ' + window.selectedFriendRequestId);
});
```

Comment: thanks ;-) I've updated our discussion thread with a new comment.